# Proof that $\left \{ f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\mid f\text{ is injective} \right \}$ is not countable by diagonalization.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So, as the title says, I want to prove that $\left \{ f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\mid f\text{ is injective} \right \}$ isn't countable - by diagonalization.

How can I create such $f$ that I cannot count?

**edit:**

Let's assume by contradiction that  $\left \{ f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\mid f\text{ is injective} \right \}$ is indeed countable.

Lets mark:

$f_0 = (a_{00},a_{01},...,a_{0n....}$

$f_1 = (a_{10},a_{11},...,a_{1n....}$

$f_2 = (a_{20},a_{21},...,a_{2n....}$

and so on...

Lets create $F' = (a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_n...$ such that $a_{i}=\begin{cases}
a_{ii}+1 & if\;a_{ii}+1\notin \left \{ a_1,...,a_{i-1} \right \}\\
max\left \{ a_1,...,a_{i-1} \right \}+1 & otherwise
\end{cases}$

Is this build sufficient?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you see how to modify the usual diagonalization construction to build an $f$ that differs from each $f$ in your list at some position while still being injective? (As a slightly more specific hint, if you think of the construction happening in 'stages' then you have only a finite number of values to avoid at each stage...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Hey Steve. I did try to modify the usual diagonalization - but didn't come with something creative so far.
Mind dropping a hint or some intuition?

Comment: My followup specific hint should cover that, hopefully. Suppose that you have your list $\langle f_n\rangle$ of functions and you're building a new $\mathcal{F}$ that isn't in the list. Then in the normal diagonalization construction you have to define $\mathcal{F}(i)$ such that it's different from $f_i(i)$; you can do that by e.g. saying $\mathcal{F}(i)=f_i(i)+1$. Here you also need to maintain injectivity – but there are only finitely many values that are on your 'forbidden' list when it comes to choosing a value for $\mathcal{F}(i)$...

Comment: You can also show that the set is uncountable by finding an uncountable set inside of it. For instance, I can think of some nice ways to find $2^\mathbb{N}$ in your set. And it's probably easier to show that that set is uncountable by diagonalization.

Comment: Modify the proof in the duplicate to ensure injectivity instead surjectivity.

Comment: @EthanDlugie I must practice diagonalization buddy, but thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Toda buddy!

Comment: @AsafKaragila added an answer, mind taking a look?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki added an answer, mind taking a look?

Comment: It looks fine. You can just add $a_{ii}$ to the set you're max'ing over. Also `\max`.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks, I apprecitate your help.